# Where to study computational geometry?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I want to solve geometry problems in online programming contests. But whenever I read them, I just find too difficult. Please suggest some books and resources which I can study computational geometry.

Comment: What types of problems do you face that are difficult to understand? Could it be a basic geometry/trig problem?

Comment: Means any algorithm I think is computationally very intensive which does not fit the time limit.

Comment: Most of geometry problems is difficult

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A classic work: [Computational Geometry in C](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html).

And there's also: http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/.

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve basic geometry problems quickly, so that it runs within the time limits of the contest, you need to make certain you have a strong grasp of writing algorithms.

This page has some good suggestions on how to get better. It is set up as a two semester course of reading.

http://mrmbdctg.freehostia.com/contest_Tipsforbeginner.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try the problem archive on TopCoder.
But you should register first.

On the filter choose:
Category: Geometry 
Division II Level: [Level One](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive&sr=&er=&sc=&sd=&class=&cat=Geometry&div1l=&div2l=1&mind1s=&mind2s=&maxd1s=&maxd2s=&wr=) or [Level Two](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive&sr=&er=&sc=&sd=&class=&cat=Geometry&div1l=&div2l=2&mind1s=&mind2s=&maxd1s=&maxd2s=&wr=).

Almost all problems have description of solutions.

They are pretty simple in comparison you choose random geometric problem from some contest archive.

On the [page](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index) you can also find a lot of tutorials, including geometric ones.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend two books (among others):

- [The Algorithm Design Manual By Steven S. Skiena](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693) - discusses algorithms in general, but has a lot of useful information about computational geometry
- [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540779736)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear your basics, this is a good starting point - https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/computational-geometry-i-1/. There are some practice problems as well in the article.

You should also read through this article - http://www.toptal.com/python/computational-geometry-in-python-from-theory-to-implementation that covers some advanced concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two excellent books, I used them as textbooks at university:

1. J D Foley, A van Dam et al. [Introduction to Computer Graphics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Computer-Graphics-James-Foley/dp/0201609215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1254749601&sr=8-1).  Addison-Wesley, 1994, ISBN 0-201-60921-5.
2. D Hearn and M P Baker. [Computer Graphics with Open GL (3rd edition)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Graphics-OpenGL-Donald-Hearn/dp/0131202383/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1254749622&sr=1-1).  Prentice-Hall, 2004, ISBN 0-13-120238-3.

[image: Introduction to Computer Graphics]

[image: Computer Graphics with Open GL]

Comment: Are they of help to these contests means they r on computer graphics

Comment: Well that really depends on the problem you want to solve; computer graphics usually involve heavy use of geometry. I'm not sure if they would help you solving your specific geometry problem.

Comment: @Aditya - I expect that they won't be of use in the contests, but your question is confusing, as computational geometry has a very specific meaning to most people. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry

Answer (score 2):

You *must* know convex hull and point-in-polygon. Often on TopCoder people create a reusable library for geometry applications, since the same is code is used many times.

Check [lbackstrom's tutorial](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index) for start. [Computional Geometry by de Berg, Cheong, van Kreveld, Overmars](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/) [edit: already mentioned by Bart] might be more than you need.

Answer (score 2):

And of course there's [Computational Geometry - An Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387961313), by Preparata and Shamos. I own it, and recommend it for an introduction to the principles. Not really a dictionary of code, though.